IOS Web Push, Notification. Pop-ups Not showing up
Pop-up not showing despite console saying it's "Requesting
PermissionNotification.requestPermission().then((result) => { permission = result === 'granted' ? true : false; });

On android devices, desktops including MacOS, is all working fine.
Tested device

Simulated Iphone 15 Pro Max - IOS 17.2
Unknown Iphone version (friend) - IOS 18 (Latest as of Dec 2024)

But the console log is only available at the simulated device.
Things that i've done to ensure Notification is allowed,

Block Pop-up (not on) - Checked
Safari WebKit Feature Flag for Notification (turned on) - Checked
Prompts are only allowed if user interacted (gesture) on IOS, so added a button to trigger the request. - Checked
Add the site to Homescreen (PWA) - Checked

Anyone encountered this issue ? Is this my problem or IOS's bug / restriction ?

Updates:
Turn up, there was some syntax error with my manifest.json which causes IOS to not thinks its a PWA. Problem solved after resolve this issue.
